# How can I use a URL in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I want just the text to show up as a link, no URL.  I've tried the basic HTML

```
<a href="www.bing.com">Check out this new website I found</a>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the internet, but Google is not a new website. `;)`

Comment: @ Nick T - Edited accordingly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
[Link text](http://www.example.com)
```

The same syntax also works in questions. See [this meta.SO feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments) for the original request.

Also, you can always click the 'help' link at the bottom-right of the comment box to bring up this text:

```
Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)
 _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will automatically be 
notified of your comment. To notify a previous commenter, mention 
their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work.
```

See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities) for known bugs.

Comment: This is, quite possibly, the most helpful answer I have ever received on StackExchange (and it's in the Meta no less). [Thank You](http://www.goldpals.com/wcms/themes/W1gold1/images/thank_you18.jpg) very much!

Comment: @Joel - It's also, quite possibly, the least effort and knowledge I've ever put into an answer.  :)